# JQ: Filter result by does not contain string OR is less than value

Tags: json, select, jq

On Ubuntu, I have

```
jq '.[] | {addr: .addr, subver: .subver, inbound: .inbound, synced_blocks: .synced_blocks} | select(.synced_blocks < 77982)'

{
  "addr": "299.247.7.254:8268",
  "subver": "/String:0.22.5.7/",
  "inbound": false,
  "synced_blocks": 77979
}
{
  "addr": "228.290.206.224:8268",
  "subver": "/String:0.22.5.6/",
  "inbound": false,
  "synced_blocks": 77980
}
{
  "addr": "208.62.262.244:55226",
  "subver": "/String:0.22.5.7/",
  "inbound": true,
  "synced_blocks": 77978
}
{
  "addr": "200.2.222.25:50452",
  "subver": "/String:0.22.5.7/",
  "inbound": true,
  "synced_blocks": 77980
}
{
  "addr": "220.92.79.44:50970",
  "subver": "/String:0.22.4.2/",
  "inbound": true,
  "synced_blocks": -2
}
{
  "addr": "45.22.228.69:57462",
  "subver": "/String:0.22.5.7/",
  "inbound": true,
  "synced_blocks": 77980
}
{
  "addr": "29.206.256.229:8268",
  "subver": "/String:0.22.5.7/",
  "inbound": false,
  "synced_blocks": 77980
}
```

Also

```
select(.subver | contains("0.22.5.7") | not)
```

works to show results where subver does not contain  "0.22.5.7". But I can't fit in an OR for both conditions.

**How do I show only results where subver does not contain  "0.22.5.7" OR .synced_blocks < 77982 ?**

Comment: It would be helpful if you could specify more precisely (in English?) what you mean by "does not contain".  (I did not downvote the question but that's the main concern I have!)

Comment: is "0.22.5.7" present in /String:0.22.4.2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main non-obvious thing here is the post-fix "not":

```
select( ( .subver | test("(^|:)0.22.5.7($|/)") | not) or
        .synced_blocks < 77982)
```

Comment: or did you suggest test bc it is a less expensive operation?

Comment: You don't specify exactly what you mean by "contains" but I doubt it corresponds to the semantics of `contains`, which might not be what you think it is.  As the proposed solution shows, `test` supports regular expressions.